# yii2 work at local but page not found on live

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i am newbie in yii2..
I dont know why my site work at local but at live server only home page is work and the other page are page not found.

### LOCAL

home page = "work"

other page = "work"

---

### LIVE SERVER

home page = "work"

other page = "page not found" (ex: site/about, site/contact, etc)

Anyone have suggestions?
Thank a lot

*nb : i'm using yii2 advanced template*

Comment: provide  some sample of your link for accessing  these pages ...

Answer (score 0):

i searched on google, the problem is because rewrite_module not activated. So after my friend activated rewrite_module on live server, my site work well :).